# How to run selenium grid with ruby watir?

Tags: ruby, automation, watir, selenium-grid

I'm working on Ruby Watir project. Currently, I want to execute test script on Selenium grid. My test script is:

```
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome
browser = Watir::Browser.new(:remote, url: '<url>:4444/wd/hub', desired_capabilities: caps)
```

But I got the error message:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `remote' for Selenium::WebDriver::Options:Class
```

Can anyone to help me resolve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome, url: '<url>:4444/wd/hub')
```